# How to insert the / between date automatically in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to change the date format while `onkeyup` in angular 11.

I have used `matdatepicker` when I enter 10121997 in input box, it should change to 10/12/1997.

In my html file,

```
<mat-form-field>
        <mat-label [translate]="'COMMON.DATE_OF_BIRTH'"></mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dob" [required]="true" formControlName="dob" (keyup)="dateofBirth(form.value)">
        <mat-hint align="start" [translate]="'SIXTH_ITERATION.MUST_BE_18_NOT_SHARED_PUBLICLY'"></mat-hint>
        
        <mat-error *ngIf="dateOfBirth.errors?.required && !dateOfBirth.errors?.matDatepickerParse" [translate]="'VALIDATORS.FIELD_REQUIRED'"></mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="dateOfBirth.errors?.matDatepickerParse" [translate]="'EIGHT_ITERATION.VALIDATORS.INVALID_FORMAT'">
        </mat-error>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dob"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #dob></mat-datepicker>
        <mat-error *ngIf="dateOfBirth.hasError('underEighteen')" [translate]="'VALIDATORS.DOB'">
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

in my ts file

```
dateofBirth(data){
  
    var date = this.datePipe.transform(this.form.get('dob')?.errors?.matDatepickerParse?.text, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log(date);
  }
```

I couldn't change the format in `dateofbirth` function. In console it returns `null` or `invalid` dates. Suggest the better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

There might be two issues. Check the following steps.

1. Check if you are passing a valid date Object to the keyUp event handler.
2. You might need to use `keyDown` event instead as it is possible you are not getting the values selected from the date picker. Generally, `keyUp` event is called when you just press it, so when your event handler is called it doesn't receive the data that's why you receive `null` or `undefined`.
3. Best way not allow user to type the date(you might need validation which is just an overhead) and let them select it through datepicker. Apply `readonly` to the input field. I have also added that in the answer.

I would recommend you to follow `3` as a suggestion.

```
<mat-form-field>
        <mat-label [translate]="'COMMON.DATE_OF_BIRTH'"></mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dob" [required]="true" formControlName="dob" (keydown)="dateofBirth(form.value)" readonly >
        <mat-hint align="start" [translate]="'SIXTH_ITERATION.MUST_BE_18_NOT_SHARED_PUBLICLY'"></mat-hint>
        
        <mat-error *ngIf="dateOfBirth.errors?.required && !dateOfBirth.errors?.matDatepickerParse" [translate]="'VALIDATORS.FIELD_REQUIRED'"></mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="dateOfBirth.errors?.matDatepickerParse" [translate]="'EIGHT_ITERATION.VALIDATORS.INVALID_FORMAT'">
        </mat-error>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dob"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #dob></mat-datepicker>
        <mat-error *ngIf="dateOfBirth.hasError('underEighteen')" [translate]="'VALIDATORS.DOB'">
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

```
dateofBirth(data){
    console.log(data) // check the values here
    const date = this.datePipe.transform('pass the date', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log(date);
  }
```

Comment: i should not use readonly in input field.

Comment: If you are using datePicker from material it is a good option to consider as when you select a date it will fill the input auto. And you don't need to add the validation to the input field to check its validity.